# How do you split a file base on a token?

Tags: unix, command-line, awk

Let's say you got a file containing texts (from 1 to N) separated by a $ 
How can a slit the file so the end result is N files?

> text1 with newlines $
>   text2 $etc... $
>   textN

I'm thinking something with awk or sed but is there any available unix app that already perform that kind of task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `split -p` *pattern*?

Hmm.  That may not be exactly what you want. It doesn't split a line, it only starts a new file when it sees the pattern.  And it seems to be supported only on BSD-related systems.

You could use something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "$"} { ... }'
```

**edit:** You might find some inspiration for the `{ ... }` part here:

http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Split-Program.html

**edit:** Thanks to comment from dmckee, but `csplit` also seems to copy the whole line on which the pattern occurs.

Comment: Hmmm, my `split` doesn't have a `-p` option - what OS is that on?

Comment: Mac OS has it. Also consider "csplit".

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X, which is based on BSD UNIX.  See http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=split

Comment: I'd figured out the RS part of the awk script it's the "..." part that still puzzled me. BTW, split doesn't have -p on cygwin.

Comment: Cygwin is based on GNU, not BSD.  But it doesn't matter, split -p isn't what you want.

Comment: See link above to a GNU awk program that splits into multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

> awk 'BEGIN{RS="$"; ORS=""} { textNumber++; print $0 > "text"textNumber".out" }' fileName

Thank to Bill Karwin for the idea.

Edit : Add the ORS="" to avoid printing a newline at the end of each files.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, the UNIX [cut](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/) command can be used for this.

```
cut -d $ -f 1- filename
```

I might have the syntax slightly off, but that should tell cut that you're using $ separated fields and to return fields 1 through the end.

You may need to escape the $.

Comment: Isn't this per line, and it does not produce multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vRS="$" '{ print $0 > "text"t++".out" }' ORS="" file
```

Answer (score 1):

using split command we can split using strings.

but csplit command will allow you to slit files basing on regular expressions as well.